# Append for HasManyThrough objects

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships, laravel-5.4

My Subject class has users with a `HasManyThrough` relationship.

```
return $subject->users; //returns an array with ids and names from the database
```

Now I want to add a dynamic `appends` variable that should not be included in the `user` class because it's not needed everywhere.

So is there a way to set this `appends` value for for the whole `HasManyThrough`object?

Comment: could you give a sample expected answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `HasManyThrough` is also a `Collection` so it's possible run over it with map:

```
$subject->users->map(function(User $user) {
  $user->setAppends(['foo', 'bar']);
  return $user;
});
```